# Is there a macro for creating traits of shared properties?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have two structs that are quite similar:

```
struct Thing1 {
   p1: i32,
   p2: i32,
   p3: i32
}

struct Thing2 {
   p1: i32,
   p2: i32,
   p3: i32,
   metadata: String
}
```

Having a trait for the common values is quite useful:

```
trait PValues {
   fn p1(&self) -> i32;
   fn p2(&self) -> i32;
   fn p2(&self) -> i32;
}

impl PValues for Thing1 {
  fn p1(&self) -> {self.p1};
  fn p2(&self) -> {self.p2};
  fn p3(&self) -> {self.p3}; 
}

impl PValues for Thing2 {
  fn p1(&self) -> {self.p1};
  fn p2(&self) -> {self.p2};
  fn p3(&self) -> {self.p3}; 
}
```

However this is laborious, duplicative and error prone.  Are there any commonly use rust macros that do this?  If not, what is the idiomatic pattern for this?

Comment: I don't know a macro for that, but I would say that a trait for common fields is unidomatic, and so are getters in general, especially in traits. If they share common _behavior_, the common behavior should be extracted to a separate struct. If they don't, and just happened to share a bunch of fields accidentally, they should not implement a common trait.

Comment: Right, but sometimes this is unavoidable because you're dealing with data structures generated by third parties.

Comment: > common behavior should be extracted to a separate struct
Is there a macro for deriving try_from

Comment: And doing... what inside?

Comment: Why not implement `Thing2` like `struct Thing2 { a: Thing1, metadata: string }`. The format in memory will be identical and you can even serialize them the same in serde.